# How to extract a list of DFS-shares where a specific server is registed as TargetPath?

Tags: powershell, depth-first-search, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I would like to get a list of DFS-Shares, where a specific server is registered as the TargetPath.

I have been trying to get this by the following code

```
`$DFSPath = "\\DFSpath"
$DFSNFolders = Get-DfsnFolder $DFSPath
foreach($DFSNFolder in $DFSNFolders )
    {
   $DFSTarget = Get-DfsnFolderTarget $DFSNFolder.path | Select Path,TargetPath | 
        Where {$DFSNFolder.TargetPath -like $servername} | 
           
    }`
```

But no matter what I try, the result $DFSTarget is always empty.

Powershell version is 5.

I have tried to adjust the Where {} clause, but no matter what I enter there, the result is empty (eventhough I know there is results).

Comment: Should be ;  Where {$_.TargetPath -like $servername} |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Match instead of like, but the same idea:

```
$ServerToFind = "server1.example.com"

$RootPath = (Get-DfsnRoot).Path
$RootTargets = Get-DfsnRootTarget -Path $RootPath
$RootTargets | Where-Object {$_.TargetPath -match $ServerToFind}
```